# Sql join with two tables max and count

Tags: sql, join, count, max

i have two tables

employee :
employee_number employee_name salary divison_id

division :
division_id division_name

How to Show division id, division name, number of employees working in each division that has the highest number of employees.

I want to have an outcome like this :

```
division_id division_name total_employee
  Z-100   | finance       |   3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT e.division_id,
               d.division_name,
               Count(1) total_employee
        FROM   employee e
               JOIN division d
                 ON e.division_id = d.division_id
        GROUP  BY e.division_id
        ORDER  BY Count(1) DESC)a
LIMIT  1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the department with most employees you should consider that more than one department can have that. So I am revising my answer and instead of top I am using Rank() with CTE to get all the divisions with most number of employees.

```
with DivisionWithMostEmployee as 
(
    select Rank()over(order by count(*) desc) RowNumber, d.division_id, d.division_name, count(*) TotalEmployee 
    from division d, employee e where d.division_id=e.division_id 
    group by d.division_id,d.division_name 
)
select Division_id,Division_name,TotalEmployee from DivisionWithMostEmployee where RowNumber=1
```